# Why !(%) in xargs doesn't work correctly?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm attempting to use the following code to omit the last file while copying the rest into a destination folder:

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1 | xargs -I% cp !(%) ~/test_dst/folder1
```

The first two pipes get the name of the latest file, and this is piped into xargs which adds that into the cp command, where I use extglob's ! wildcard to copy everything else. The problem is though, this copies every file! I tried to debug this by determining what the first part of this prints (set -x is on):

```
> ~/test_src/folder1$ ls -Art | tail -n 1
+ tail -n 1
+ ls --color=auto -Art
file4
```

success! this is the actual correct file! I then tried to print it with the wildcard:

```
> ~/test_src/folder1$ ls -Art | tail -n 1 | xargs -I% echo !(%)
+ tail -n 1
+ ls --color=auto -Art
+ xargs -I% echo file1 file2 file3 file4
file1 file2 file3 file4
```

and it includes the omitted file?? I tried to hardcode the command by itself, and what do you know, it actually works right:

```
> ~/test_src/folder1$ echo !(file4)
+ echo file1 file2 file3
file1 file2 file3
```

what am I doing wrong? this is basically my first attempt at a shell script and it's driving me crazy, any tips are greatly appreciated. I would prefer to debug this specific method (this is just the way I thought of doing it), but I am definitely open to any suggestions or replacement methods of doing this. thank you!

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not going to work. The two features you're trying to combine are interpreted in the wrong order.

Extglobs are a feature of the shell (the command interpreter), and as you noticed in the "trace" output, they're expanded by bash *before* the 'xargs' command is actually run.

If extglobs – or any globs, really – were passed as-is to xargs (or to 'echo', or to 'cp'), it wouldn't know what to do with them; e.g. 'cp' would think that "!(%)" or "!(file1)" is literally the file name to be copied.

xargs, on the other hand, is *not* part of the shell – it's a standalone program like any other, and bash doesn't know the significance of the "%", nor does it know that you're passing another command to xargs.

So when the `!(%)` extglob is being expanded, it is only expanded *once* for the entire command – not once for each xargs input, but only once for the literal `%` that Bash sees in the command. This of course results in **all files that aren't named `%`**.

---

One way to do this is to replace xargs with the shell's own expansions – unlike xargs, shell variables are expanded **before** extglobs, so if you had the file name in a variable...

```
except_file=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
```

...you could use that in the extglob:

```
cp !("$except_file") ~/test_dst/folder1
```

(The two can be combined into `cp !("$(ls...)") ~/...`.)

It is also possible to do the opposite and keep xargs, but remove the extglob. Instead of getting just the last file with `tail` and then needing extra steps to get everything else, you can directly get *everything except* the last file using `head` (negative parameters for both 'head' and 'tail' mean "except the last N"):

```
ls -Art | head -n -1 | xargs -I% cp % ~/test_dst/folder1
```

or, to let xargs do its job of invoking one `cp` for all files at once, assuming your system has GNU Coreutils with the `cp -t <target>` option:

```
ls -Art | head -n -1 | xargs -d '\n' cp -t ~/test_dst/folder1
```

---

Side note: File names on Linux can contain line breaks. Many of the above examples assume you don't have such file names, because you really shouldn't – but it *is* something to consider when writing scripts to be deployed on unknown systems, and "defensive" programming would typically involve tools like `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` to work with null-separated lists, instead of newline-separated ones. (Shell wildcards generally deal with it fine.)

Comment: thank you so so much, this was an amazing guide! I ended up going with your 2nd solution, as it didn't require the need of an extra variable. I really appreciate your detailed explanations on why things happened, as I am very much trying to get into bash programming. this is amazing!